# Reality check: irreducible over a non-algebraically closed field means replace closed sets with Galois-stable closed sets, right?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I am requesting a reality check. I'm pretty sure of something but my algebraic geometry education is insufficiently comprehensive to give me full conviction, and I can't readily find the answer in texts.

Say $V=\operatorname{Spec}A$ is an affine variety (i.e. reduced, finite-type scheme) over a field $k$ which is not algebraically closed. Then $V$ is irreducible as a topological space if and only if $A$ is an integral domain (so that there is a unique minimal prime ideal, namely zero). I would like to understand irreducibility in terms of the Zariski topology on the $\overline k$-points, where $\overline k$ is $k$'s algebraic closure. It seems to me it's the following, and my question is if this is right:

Let $\Gamma=\operatorname{Gal}(\overline k/ k)$ be the absolute Galois group of $k$. Then $\Gamma$ acts in a natural way on the set $V(\overline k)$ of $\overline k$-points of $V$. The set $V(\overline k)$ gets a topology via its natural bijection with the closed points of $V\otimes_k \overline k$, which have a subspace topology induced from the Zariski topology on $V\otimes_k \overline k$. I think $V$'s irreducibility should be equivalent to the statement that $V(\overline k)$ is not the union of two proper closed subsets each of which is stable under the $\Gamma$-action. Is this right?

I think this because my understanding is that stability under $\Gamma$-action is equivalent to "defined over $k$", and irreducibility of $V$ (since it is a $k$-scheme) ought to mean that it is not reducible into proper closed subsets that are defined over $k$. But I am not immediately seeing how to connect this with the definition in terms of the irreducibility of $V$ itself (i.e. $\operatorname{Spec} A$) as a topological space.

I will be satisfied with an explanation, but if you have recommendations of chapters or sections of texts where this issue is discussed, I would be delighted by that too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think your claim is false. Consider $X = $ Spec $\mathbb{C}$ over $k=\mathbb{R}$. Then $X$ is irreducible, but $X_{\mathbb{C}} = $ Spec $(\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R})$ is clearly not irreducible (not even connected).The proper closed subsets of $X_{\mathbb{C}}$ are $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$. Neither of these is $\Gamma$-invariant (where $\Gamma $ is $\mu_2$ acting via complex conjugation). So, your expected equivalence does not hold.

Comment: I think this is the kind of thing your'e looking for, no? https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04KY

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar This example is actually what the OP wants - $X_\Bbb C$ is not the union of two $\Gamma$-invariant proper closed subsets, and $X$ is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I misread the claim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is true, and your concept of why is basically accurate as well. Here's a rigorous accounting. Your condition on $V(\overline{k})$ can be phrased in terms of the map $V_{\overline{k}}\to V$ by a combination of the following four facts:

- $V(\overline{k}) = (V\times_k \overline{k})(\overline{k})$;
- the topology on $V_{\overline{k}}(\overline{k})$ is the induced topology from $V_\overline{k}$;
- the $\overline{k}$-points of $V_{\overline{k}}$ are dense in every closed subset;
- and the Galois action on $V_{\overline{k}}(\overline{k})$ is the restriction of the Galois action on $V_\overline{k}$.

From these we may conclude that irreducible closed subsets of $V(\overline{k})$ are in bijection with irreducible closed subsets of $V_\overline{k}$, and this bijection respects the Galois action.

Next, every irreducible component of $V_\overline{k}$ maps down to an irreducible component of $V$ and this map is surjective ([Stacks 04KX](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04KX)). Further, the Galois group acts on the irreducible components of $V_\overline{k}$, and the fibers of the map from the set of irreducible components of $V_\overline{k}$ to the set of irreducible components of $V$ are exactly the Galois orbits ([Stacks 04KY](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04KY)).

This proves your assertion. In one direction, if $V=W\cup Z$ is reducible, then $W_\overline{k}$ and $Z_\overline{k}$ are proper closed $G$-invariant subsets of $V_\overline{k}$ having union $V_\overline{k}$. On the other hand, if $V_\overline{k}$ can be written as a union of two proper closed subsets $X,Y$ which are stable under the $G$-action, then we can partition the irreducible components of $V_\overline{k}$ in to two disjoint nonempty collections, both of which are stable under the Galois action: those irreducible components that are only in $X$, and all the others. Since the fibers of the map from irreducible components of $V_\overline{k}$ to irreducible components of $V$ are exactly the Galois orbits, $V$ must have multiple irreducible components.

Comment: Thanks so much. I think I may be missing a subtlety in your last paragraph. I'm not sure of the purpose of the sentence about considering the irreducible components in $X$ vs. not... Maybe it's just that you want the partition with 2 parts, so you can say there are at least 2 irred. components? When I got to that sentence in the paragraph, I thought we were already done: the irred. components of $V_{\overline k}$ are each in either $X$ or $Y$ but are not all in one or the other, and it follows there's at least one in $X$ but not $Y$, and at least one in $Y$ but not $X$. Galois stability of

Comment: $X,Y$ translates this into the statement that there's a whole Galois orbit of irred. components in $X$ but not $Y$, and likewise in $Y$ but not $X$; and the statement about the fibers of the map on irreducible compoments induced by $V_{\overline k}\rightarrow V$ translates this into the desired claim... I guess this is essentially what you were doing, but just putting together the finish in a slightly different way? Or am I actually missing something?

(Thanks again, this was a very satisfying answer. +1.)

Comment: I was being extra explicit about how one sees there must be multiple irreducible components of $V$. I think what you've written is the same idea, just recorded in a slightly different order. Happy to help!